# Am I missing a step while deriving a conclusion given a set of premises? Discrete Mathematics And Functional Programming book.

Tags: logic

I am reading the book "[Discrete Mathematics and Functional Programming](https://isbnsearch.org/isbn/9781590282601)" by Thomas VanDrunen, focusing only in the Math part.

Exercise **3.9.7** confused me because I am not so sure on how to connect one of the premises. Here's the problem:

(a) t ⟹ q
(b) q ⟹ r
(c) (t ⟹ r) ⟹ w
(d) p ∨ t
(e) ∴ w

Here's the procedure I followed:

(i) t ⟹ r
Using (a), (b), and the transitive law.

(ii) w
Then I went immediately to the conclusion, w, by (i), (c), and Modus Ponens. I am not so sure however, because I am not using (d) at all.

At some point I told myself, most likely (d) and (ii) must have the form of a conjunction, and then I can conclude w, by means of specialization.

The exercise seems simple, but I don't know, have you guys/gals solved a similar problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset the formulas in your MSE questions, it makes them much easier to read. As for the mathematics, your proof is quite correct - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is quite correct. It is very common in mathematics and in reasoning about programs to have more background information than you actually need. In your exercise, as $p$ doesn't appear in any premise other than (d) and as (d) gives no information about the value of the other variables when $p$ is true, (d) is not relevant.

Comment: Hey Rob Arthan!
Thank you very much.
Happy weekend!
P.S. Sorry for the MathJax hiccup.
--
Caleb